# Typeahead.js - Tokens in dataset to filter result (secret/custom keyword)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, typeahead.js

I'd like a feature where I can have a hidden "keyword" which will not be shown in the input on autocompleted/selected nor in the results, but WILL be searched on.

At first, I thought that 'tokens' was the answer (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#datum), but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I have tried to make the dataset like this:

```
{
    name: "Go to Home",
    value: "home",
    tokens: ["secret","mykeyword"]
}
```

But it doesn't bring up the result "Go to home".

Any ideas?

This would work:

```
{
    name: "Go to Home",
    value: "home secret mykeyword",
    tokens: ["secret","mykeyword"]
}
```

But I dont want the "secret mykeyword" to show up in the input.

Comment: I think you will not get things as you intend.
You may try another approach. Maybe add your hidden word to the remote or prefech url query

Comment: How would that help? And yes, I am prefetching my datasets. How would I filter them with the query? The results outputted come from arrays.